Hide Google group in address list
How can I hide a group in my Google Workspace in the address lists of users (e.g. GMail)?
I have already found that it works via GAM in this forum, but I don't have GAM yet. There must also be a possibility via the Google API - but which one?
Who has a short code example for me?
Thank you
I found only a solution about GAM.
